# Need help in identifying this font

Tags: font-identification

What is this font?

[image: sample]

Here is the link to the pdf file: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1101.0070.pdf

Is this the [Egizio URW](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/urw/egizio-urw/) font??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example is set using [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) and is Knuth's [Computer Modern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Modern) — although the PDF processing doesn't appear to have done it a great deal of good.

[image: Computer Modern]

Comment: I was just thinking about LaTeX...since it's an academic publication....thanks for clearing my doubts! :-)

Comment: The PDF itself is fine; it's just that the person asking the question has taken a screenshot at very low resolution (or their PDF viewer is buggy).